# nginx multiple frontend servers with SSL DNS setup?

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, high-availability

I have my backend app server setup and working with a single reverse proxy nginx setup on the west coast. It also does caching. Now I want to include another frontend server in a east coast region that can do caching. I can find lots of resources that speak about a single frontend to many backend setup however nothing that speaks about multiple frontend to single backend.

I cant figure out the DNS issue. I use google domains and it wont let me add another @ record that points to the other server.

[Duplicate Record Google Domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuFdx.png)

***ADDITIONAL INFO

I would go the CDN route, but the site is ~ 550K pages and each around 40Kb. About 20GB. Its also rather high traffic.

I am okay with non-trivial.

Currently hosted with ramnode vps's

SSL may be an issue. Basically can 1 cert work on multiple servers provided they have the same setup?

Comment: Are you looking for a CDN?

Comment: What are you referring to using "SSL" in the title of your question?

Comment: SSL may be part of an issue after I get the setup. Same CERT, multiple servers.

Comment: The cert is not tied to a specific server, but to a specific or multiple domains. It's quite possible to use the same cert on multiple servers.

Comment: im just trying to figure out why nginx has a geoip feature even built in then?

Comment: To serve different content to different visitors from around the world for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use multiple `A` records, one for each machine. But, regarding your [high-availability](/questions/tagged/high-availability) tag: You won't get this via this technique.

Alternatively, you could use [Anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) or a [Content delivery network aka CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

> SSL may be an issue. Basically can 1 cert work on multiple servers provided they have the same setup?

Yes.

Comment: I tried to add another @ A record and google domains would not allow it.

Comment: According to the docs this should be possible, and personally I can't see any reason why it wouldn't / shouldn't.

Comment: It says "duplicate record" and wont allow it. Here is a screenshot [link](http://i.imgur.com/ciBz3Tn.png)

Comment: @user1669039 In fact it's correct: It's duplicate, because the record you're  trying to add exists already. In your example, it's called "fe2". You would have to change the data, aka the IP you've entered.

Comment: This won't help achieve the stated aim of geographic load balancing. It may even the load between the two servers, but not on any sensible basis. A CDN makes more sense.

Comment: i tried removing fe2 and adding it as another @ but it still said duplicate record.

Comment: @Tim Yeah, I tried to point this out in my answer.

Comment: @user1669039 Can't help you out then; maybe you've to speak to the Google support.

Answer (score 1):

I think you possibly need a content distribution network, rather than another web server trying to serve the same domain. There are a number of CDNs, including CloudFlare, MaxCDN, Amazon CloudFront, Akami, etc. CloudFlare has a free tier which is adequate for some, plus business plans. A CDN can cache pages if it's set up properly.

If you want two web servers under your control you probably need a geographic load balancer, which is not trivial to set up yourself. You're better off using a service to help with it.

I believe you can put multiple A records into DNS, but you can't control who gets served which record. I wouldn't go down that route personally.

Comment: Would a base size of cached pages near 20GB and about a TB of traffic a month be expensive?

Comment: How do you manage to generate 20GB of pages that are worthy of caching? CloudFlare has a free plan, but I don't know how much of that they'd cache - probably a lot. CloudFront would be around $85/month if it's mostly USA traffic - check out https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/ and https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/

Comment: thats not bad for cloudfront

Comment: The other advantage is they have a huge global network, many locations in the USA and lots around the world. You just have to be careful with your caching headers and configuration to get pages cached - many CDNs cache static resources (jpeg/css/js) but are rightly wary about caching pages unless specifically set up to. $100/month isn't bad for this. Remember each edge location could download your resources so you will still use a decent amount of bandwidth, but less.